# gsub: How to extract words between two words

Tags: r, regex, string

I know a lot of people have already posted some issues related to mine, but I couldn't found the correct solution.

I have a lot of sentences like: "Therapie:  I like the elephants so much Indication"

I want to extract all the words between "Therapie:" and "Indication" in the provided example above would it be "I like the elephants so much".

When I use my code I get always the next 3 words back. What am I doing wrong?

```
my_df <- c("Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication")

These are sentences out of the documents and I need just all the words between "Therapie: and Indikation:"

Examples: 
 ____________________________________________________________________________ _____    Diagnose:   Blepharochalasis    Therapie:   Oberlidplastik und Fettresektion mediales und nasales Pocket   Indikation: 

  ____________________________________________________________________________ _____    Diagnose:   Mammahypoplasie    Therapie:   Dual Plane Augmentation bds. über IMF Schnitt  Indikation: 



exc <- sub(".*?\\bTherapie\\W+(\\w+(?:\\W+\\w+){0,2}).*", "\\1", my_df, to = "documents")`, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `str_match`. `\\s*` allows to trim whitespace.

```r
str <- "Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication"

library(stringr)
str_match(str, "Therapie:\\s*(.*?)\\s*Indication")[, 2]
# [1] "I like the elephants so much"
```

What about a custom function?

```r
str_between <- function(str, w1, w2){
  stringr::str_match(str, paste0(w1, "\\s*(.*?)\\s*", w2))[, 2]
}

str_between(str, "Therapie:", "Indication")
# [1] "I like the elephants so much"
```

Comment: Nice, +1, but perhaps you should include either the library call or `stringr::str_match`

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```r
my_df <- c("Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication")
sub("^Therapie: (.*) Indication$", "\\1", my_df)
#> [1] "I like the elephants so much"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code doesn't work. Could you rewrite mine (using sub) just with the addition that it stops at Indication? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Selina1 I'm not sure what you mean - using exactly the string you gave and exactly the code I used I get exactly the result above. Can you explain what you mean by "it doesn't work?"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The string is just an example, I have a df with many text files (I use quanteda) and when I run your code I get back the entire sentences (the entire text), when I use mine I get back the first three words after therapy. Could you adjust my line of code so that I get back all the words until Indication appears?

Comment: @Selina1 so you don't have the word "Indication" in every line? Or is it that you _do_ have the word "Indication", but it is not necessarily at the end of the sentence? Perhaps you could give us a couple of extra examples so we can write an appropriate regex - there's no way to easily just adjust yours until we see more clearly what you need.

Comment: I added some examples. The documents are stored in a df.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `strsplit`:

```
str <- "Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication"

!strsplit(str, " ")[[1]] %in% c("Therapie:", "Indication") -> x
paste0(strsplit(str, " ")[[1]][x], collapse = ' ')
#"I like the elephants so much"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(str, whitespace = ".*:\\s+|\\s+Indication.*")
[1] "I like the elephants so much"
```

#### data

```
str <- "Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with a match only:

```
str <- "Therapie: I like the elephants so much Indication"
regmatches(str, regexpr("\\bTherapie:\\h*\\K.*?(?=\\h*\\bIndication\\b)", str, perl=TRUE))
```

Output

```
[1] "I like the elephants so much"
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bTherapie:` A word boundary to prevent matching a partial word, match the word `Therapie` and `:`
- `\h*\K` Match optional spaces and clear clear what is matched so far
- `.*?` Match as least as possible
- `(?=\h*\bIndication\b)` Positive lookahead, assert optional spaces and the word `Indication` to the right

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDh3ac4MiWl@gBi6eRQukndbknj4QXTNlwi@PYxKOj4Df8vpaQscNqDmpjERk9HGCD4B0FmAgoU2a45QdpgeTqGYb15Z7PfVrUTui82O6ak66WFanpF0Qpx/u0QuUEcD02v@@6L@T@pMKqFTx5JQjddrmdjSnkD).